# How to make "modal conformation" functionality in this function call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

When i m calling this below function in script, i will get a popup dialog box to do some instructions.

Here is my sample code:

```
function updateStatus(instrxnID){
            exporter.fn.childWindow({
                instrxnID : instrxnID,
                url:'pgks/fund/update/view.page'
            },'pgks','Popup',{top:100,height:459,width:884,left:200});
        }
```

**exporter.fn.childWindow** will call the below function to open popup'

```
childWindow : function(elements,path,title,setting){
        setting = setting != undefined ? setting : {top:100,height:300,width:400,left:200};
        var keys = exporter.fn.keys(elements);
        var offset = "width="+setting.width+",height="+setting.height+",top="+setting.top+",left="+setting.left;
        myWin = open("", "displayWindow", offset+",scrollbars=no,status=no,dependent=yes,directories=no,menubar=no,personalbar=no");
        myWin.document.open();
        myWin.document.write("<html><head>");
        myWin.document.write("</head><body><form name='form' action='"+elements.url+"' type='post'>");
        for ( var a = 0; a < keys.length; a++) {
            myWin.document.write('<input type="hidden" name="'+keys[a]+'" value="'+elements[keys[a]]+'">');
        }
        myWin.document.write("</form><script type='text/javascript'>form.method=\'post\';form.submit();</script></body></html>");
        myWin.document.close();
    }
```

After finishing those instruction ,i should return to the main page or parent page of this popup.

Note: By clicking background page or another link, this modal should not disapper.

Example: i need to attain something like this [example](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

Comment: So you're looking for a confirmation popup? How many different ways is the modal going to be used?

Comment: @RichPeck: only i need confirmation popup

Answer (score 1):

Attach either a click handler to your submit buttons, or a submit handler to the form. In this handler hide (`display: none;`) your popup or, if you're using a window object for your pop up, call `.close()` on the instance.

EDIT:

```
$(".my-button").on("click", function() {
  myWin.close();
});
```

Comment: can you please give an example how to use click handler or submit handler to this code?

Comment: You don't give enough information to give you the exact code, but I can give you the basic idea. I'd need at least some html to make this specific.